# How to map 2 classes using model mapper, Entity to Dto

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, modelmapper

I want to convert two objects with same attributes using model mapper. How ever I cant because of many to many relationship.

```
private User fromEntity(UserEntity userEntity) {
LOGGER.info("Converting userEntity to user model with Id" + 
userEntity.getUserId());
User user = modelMapper.map(userEntity,User.class);
LOGGER.info("Converted userEntity to user model with Id" + 
userEntity.getUserId());
return user;
}
```

I have User and UserEntity classes. They are mapped with Role and RoleEntity classess:

Here is my User class:

```
public class User {

    private Long userId;


    private String userUsername;
    private String userName;
    private String userSurname;
    private String password;
    private String addres;
    private String eMail;
    private boolean active = false;

    private String key;
    //@JsonBackReference
    private Set<Role> role ;


    public User(){
        role = new HashSet<>();

    }
```

Role Class:

```
  public class Role {

private Long roleId;

    private String role;

    private Set<User> user;

    public Role(){
        user = new HashSet<>();
    }

    //@JsonManagedReference
    public Set<User> getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    }
```

UserEntity Class:

```
@Entity
@Table( name="users" )
public class UserEntity {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "userId")
    private Long userId;

    private String userUsername;
    private String userName;
    private String userSurname;
    private String password;

    private String addres;

    private String eMail;

    private boolean active;

    private String key;


    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="userId")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="roleId")}
    )
    private Set<RoleEntity> roleEntities;

    public UserEntity(){
        active=false;
        roleEntities = new HashSet<>();

    }
```

and RoleEntity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
public class RoleEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long roleId;

    private String role;

    @ManyToMany //( mappedBy = "roleEntities") //Bunu kaldırdım
    private Set<UserEntity> userEntities ;


    public RoleEntity(){
        userEntities = new HashSet<>();
    }
```

It gives me error when I login correctly:

ModelMapper mapping errors: 1) Converter org.modelmapper.internal.converter.CollectionConverter@735060fc failed to convert java.util.Set to java.util.Set. 1 error

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the error message or full stacktrace? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I solved the problem and added solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my RoleEntity class attribute from:

```
@ManyToMany //( mappedBy = "roleEntities") 
private Set<UserEntity> userEntities ;
```

to this:

```
@ManyToMany (mappedBy = "roleEntities", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<UserEntity> userEntities ;
```

That is how I resolved the problem.